# Numpy Array shape changes when changing dtype

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Why does changing the dtype of elements of a numpy array changes the shape of the array? I am new to numpy and I was trying to change the dtype to np.float16 from existing np.int32. Doing that changed the shape of the array, but changing to np.float32 doesn't modify the shape.

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> arr1=np.array([1,2,3,4]
>>> arr1
array([1, 2, 3, 4])
>>> arr1.shape
(4,)
>>> arr1.dtype=np.float16
>>> arr1
array([  5.96046448e-08,   0.00000000e+00,   1.19209290e-07,
     0.00000000e+00,   1.78813934e-07,   0.00000000e+00,
     2.38418579e-07,   0.00000000e+00], dtype=float16)
>>> arr1.shape
(8,)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because changing the data type of the array changes what the bytes that are actually stored mean, and how many of them make up one value.
Your initial array probably has the data type `int32`, therefore each of the four values consists of four bytes:

```
a = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4], dtype=np.int32)
a
>>> array([1, 2, 3, 4], dtype=int32)
bytes(a)
>>> b'\x01\x00\x00\x00\x02\x00\x00\x00\x03\x00\x00\x00\x04\x00\x00\x00'
```

Changing the data type does not change the stored bytes, but just what they mean:

```
a.dtype = np.float16
bytes(a)
>>> b'\x01\x00\x00\x00\x02\x00\x00\x00\x03\x00\x00\x00\x04\x00\x00\x00'
a
>>> array([  5.96046448e-08,   0.00000000e+00,   1.19209290e-07,
     0.00000000e+00,   1.78813934e-07,   0.00000000e+00,
     2.38418579e-07,   0.00000000e+00], dtype=float16)
```

To actually convert the values, use `.astype`:

```
a.astype(np.float32)
>>> array([ 1.,  2.,  3.,  4.], dtype=float32)
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be using the atrtibute dtype to "change" the dtype of the array. You can also see that the new numbers don't make sense in comparison with the original ones.

Instead you should use `arr1.astype(np.float16)`.

My guess is that by just changing the dtype diretly you just tell numpy to change how much memory it reads for each element. Thus since you reduce from float32 to float16, which is half the memory representation, you get double the size.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the datatype of an array, you should do `arr1.astype(np.float16)`.

I'm not completely sure about this, but I'm guessing that numpy calculates the shape by dividing the memory usage of the array by the size of the datatype.

If you modify `dtype` directly, it the array still thinks its elements have the same size, so you might get a different answer.